# Can you Wish to teleport someone into a reversed Magic Circle?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation, wish

The rules of *[magic circle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-circle)* state that a being of the target type cannot enter/exit except by use of teleport/planar travel, succeeding on a Cha Saving throw.

If I go by the description, I read it as: to keep them out they cannot enter; to keep them in, they cannot exit. However, it does not seem to prevent movement/teleport in the opposite direction.

Can a wish spell be used to summon/teleport a creature into a Magic Circle that was cast to keep them in?

Comment: In the current state of the question, a reversed Magic Circle is the complete red herring. The true question is can you use Wish to teleport an unwilling creature to a specified point.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just use *gate*, which does exactly this thing?

Comment: Gate only works if they are on another plane. In this instance, they are not.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, you can.

Or at least you can try.

### Using *wish* to duplicate a lower level spell

*[Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)* explicitly allows you to "duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower", that might be one way to go.

You mentioned teleporting and summoning.  The *[teleport](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleport)* spell itself is probably not what you want, since it actually transports someone or something from the location of the caster to some other location, and you want to fetch someone (or something).  There are other summoning spells that you could use *wish* to emulate.  There's not necessarily a lot of advantage to that, except that you don't have to supply the emulated spell's material components. That can be a real bonus, some of them are a bit icky.

### Freestyling it

But you don't need no stinking lower level spell!  You have a *wish*!  You can do anything you want!

*Wish* also says:

> You might be able to achieve something beyond the scope of the above examples. State your wish to the GM as precisely as possible. The GM has great latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance; the greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes wrong. This spell might simply fail, the effect you desire might only be partly achieved, or you might suffer some unforeseen consequence as a result of how you worded the wish.

So, you can just wish that a demon (or whatever) would appear in your magic circle.

The easy way:

You can go the easy route and say it just like that. "I cast *wish*. I wish {fill-in-the-blank} to be transported to my magic circle." Easy-peasy, assuming you have *wish* on your spell list that day, or have it available through some other means.  Take what, 30 seconds?  Besides, how bad could it be?  You can always use *wish* again to undo anything that doesn't go quite right.

The hard way:

Or, you could spend years at it.  You could try summoning weaker creatures of whatever type you you're interested in and work your way up.  You could attempt to gather specific information on the particular entity you want to entrap and bind to your will.  You could conduct careful research in obscure libraries, research new spells, engage in field expeditions to gather useful materials, enlist allies to assist you in your quest, build elaborate containment facilities, acquire strange and potent arcane skills and artifacts, suborn governments, subjugate peoples, consume the guilty and innocent alike to use their essences to fuel your quest for power, and then finally after a lifetime of preparation, you can use that final wish to have that celestial, elemental, fey, fiend, or undead dragged by your unstoppable arcane might into your magic circle, there to be compelled to do your bidding for all eternity!  What could possibly go wrong?

So, yes, you can use wish to summon anything you want into your magic circle, and it could be the work of but a few moments, or the work of a lifetime.

### Read the fine print and don't try this at home

*Wish* potentially has some repercussions, nothing serious, just the usual legalese about operating heavy machinery, necrotic damage, weakness, permanent disability, but nothing to worry about.

And of course, wishings and summonings sometimes go awry, so it's entirely possible things won't go the way you envision.

Comment: Teleport requires the being to be willing, so using Wish to duplicate that effect would not work (assuming the creature was unwilling).

Comment: True. Although the summoned being might just be willing, you never know.

Comment: @Jack it is probably worth editing into your answer though. A vast majority of creatures are not going to be willing to be teleported to a magical prison they cannot escape.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Nothing in spell description says that target is aware of teleport destination. It is leap of faith of some sort.

Comment: @AntiDrondert I'm aware of that however the default assumption is that enemy creatures are unwilling. Regardless I just think it is worth mentioning for completeness.

Answer (score -5):

**Yes**

The real question is if *Wish* can Cast *Teleport* on an Enemy.

Some of these arguments suggest that you cannot because the Target must be willing. However, they miss the point.

*Wish* specifically says:

> You don’t need to meet **any** requirements in that spell, **including** costly components. The spell simply takes effect.

One of the requirements of *Teleport* is that the Target is willing. It doesn't just ignore Components, it can ignore **any** of the Spell's requirements. Thus, *Wish* can ignore this requirement and Target anyone with *Teleport*, willing or otherwise. It can even be used across vast distances, as the Range is also a requirement.

However, Mishaps are not a requirement, but a feature, so you still have to worry about those.

Comment: I’m not sure this is quite right. When *wish* ignores requirements, I think it’s ignoring any requirements for casting the spell. That *teleport* targets a willing creature is just an effect of the spell, not a requirement for casting it. The issue I have with this reading is that I can interpret *any* part of the spell effect as a requirement. It’s a *requirement* of *fireball* to deal fire damage - I’ll ignore that and do psychic instead.

Comment: If Target isn't a requirement, what is? Fire Damage of a *Fireball* is part of the mechanics of the Spell, not a requirement. Something is **required** when it has to happen or be met for the Spell, and is thus quite clearly a requirement. *Teleport* **requires** the Target be willing—so any argument that it isn't a requirement is truly ridiculous—whereas Fire Damage is just the **effect** of *Fireball*. You're suggesting  any part of a Spell can be altered because of this very logical reading, and that would take Olympian levels of mental gymnastics to reach such a conclusion.

Comment: Additionally the DMG provides rules for swapping the Damage Type for Spells, for flavor or theme, which very obviously shows they aren't a *requirement* for the Spell.

Comment: This logic is going to create all sorts of weird and probably unintended interactions. Up to and including raising unwilling targets from the dead, or ones whose souls aren't capable of coming back, using the Raise Dead spell. Sounds like you'd make your life as a DM pretty miserable, and you can't even rely on such shenanigans to eventually stop as the Wish spell burns out.

Comment: Also the DMG rules you mention create *new* spells, they don't allow casters to swap them out on the fly. There's a difference between using Wish to cast Iceball even though it wasn't really a spell before if the DM is okay with it existing, and using a spell to bypass requirements that end up making the spell much, much stronger or do completely different things.

Comment: Yes, this logic would let you ignore the requirement that the Target soul be free and willing. What part of "mightiest Spell" shouldn't be able to do that, and again, the free and willing is a crystal clear *requirement* of the Spell. 5e invented the concept that Wish can burn out; this isn't some historic feature of a very famous Spell. This is all just an argument that 5e poorly designed yet another Spell, not that we should avoid implimenting it exactly as it says to. Purposefully attempting to screw over your Players instead of applying a Spell exactly as written is laughably cruel.

Comment: Spells applying only to certain types of target isn't a requirement to cast them; it's just the effect of what the spells do. See XGE pp 85-86. If you aim _hold person_ at a vampire, you can still expend a slot and cast the spell; being a humanoid isn't a casting requirement the same way having the material components is (you just straight-up can't cast it without those). But then the spell will do nothing, because the effect of the spell is to restrain a humanoid, not to restrain an undead.

Comment: If _wish_ lets you arbitrarily remove words from a spell's effect, then why would it need to do anything else except duplicate a spell? Replicate your favorite buff spell (_haste_ is a good choice) and remove the words "until the spell ends" from the effects. Replicate _disintegrate_ and remove the words "if this damage leaves it with zero hit points" so that it instantly and permanently kills anything. Hell, remove the words "a creature you can see within range" and "the target must make a Dexterity saving throw" and annihilate anyone on the planet without a save.

Comment: Those are all things _wish_ can do—but they certainly don't fall under "replicate a spell", because that's not the effect of those spells. So they incur the risks of "the GM can veto any or all of it at will" and "you might never be able to cast _wish_ again".

Comment: Spell Effects are not the same as Spell requirements. Every one of your interpretations reduces "you don't have to meet *any* requirements, including costly components" to "you can only ignore Components requirements". You have to blatantly be ignorant of either the English language, or 5e's clear ruling that things work precisely as described, to reach any such conclusion. The Spell says it can ignore *any* requirement, and the Target of *Teleport* being willing is a requirement of the Spell, not some Effect of it. There's no other possible reading, only refusal to apply the Spell as written.